# Django app without ORM Model, but using data from a Public REST API

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am wondering if it would be possible to create a Django app which doesn't get it's data from the default Django ORM, but from a third party REST API? Is that at all possible? And if it it, does anyone have any pointers to examples or further reference ?

From what I have found up till now I can use django-rest-framework to build a REST API on top of a Django ORM model. In my case I won't have a Django ORM Model since all information will be coming and going through a third party REST API (JSON or XML).

Answer (score 1):

By definition Django is ORM framework so not using the ORM is kind of pointless, however it is very rich fullstack framework so it is absolutely possible to use just some components of it like template system or routing. If you don't want the orm just don't use it.